# Why does RDC disconnects even during GPO update with fDenyTSConnections set to 0?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-firewall

Group policy is setting remote desktop allowing to be used. Computers are set for remote connection through any version of Remote Desktop.
Remote Desktop is allowed through local firewall default port 3389.
Group policy is set to Allow Remote Desktop exceptions.
Registry shows fDenyTSConnections set to 0 which should allow Remote Desktop connections.
Computers are Windows 7 and Server 2008. For some reason with this all allowed I am getting this error every time group policy updates itself or is forced:

[image: Your Remote Desktop Services session has ended]

I think I have everything set correctly. Is there anyway to stop the connection from disconnecting after each group policy update?

**EDIT 1** - Found that when the GP Updates it removes or updates or fixes an issue with the registry key and replaces it which drops the connection. ***IS THERE A WAY TO FIX THIS SO THE CONNECTION IS NOT LOST?***

Comment: It shouldn't be disconnecting just because GP refreshed, I think your problem lays elsewhere.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Seems to correlate. When I do a GP Update it disconnects. Looking at the logs when the GP updates it disconnects.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Information added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this issue.

I have 2 group policies. 1 that disabled remote desktop usage and 1 that enables it.

During group policy application the first policy applies settings and then the second policy overwrites it but considering it applies the first policy first it disconnects the session. Disabled that policy setting and it now works correctly.